# Linkedin sharing popup in ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, linkedin-api

I am not able to find popup for sharing link on LinkedIn.
I got REST API and also called successfully.

```
    let url: String = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares?format=json"
    let payloadStr: String = "{\"comment\":\"I_SHARE_EXXO5__llEO_0009099\",\"visibility\":{\"code\":\"anyone\"}}"

    let payloadData = payloadStr.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

LISDKAPIHelper.sharedInstance().postRequest(url, body: payloadData, success: { (response) in
```

Do i need to add custom popup from my side in app?

Answer (score 0):

LinkedIn is not providing any dialog or popup for sharing text so if you need to show pop up you have to design your custom popup.